# Help with symbolicating iphone crash logs

Tags: objective-c

How can i symbolicate an iphone crash with symbolicate crash pearl script?
Help me with setting up pearl script on mac and corresponding commands.

Comment: please rephrase your question. nothing in what you said makes sense.

Comment: lol +1 for asking a question that does not make sense! (: it made me smile

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Xcode Organizer takes care of it for you now...

[Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports)

I don't think the original "symbolicatecrash" script comes with Xcode anymore (as detailed here: http://furbo.org/2008/08/08/symbolicatifination/)

@stillstanding & Jacob - the 2nd link is for you both. I'm sure Prasanth's question will make perfect sense after you've read it. Please refrain from commenting if you don't have anything to contribute.